# Word search with 2 conditions PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I would like to know if it is possible to give 2 conditions to the search engine on my site. 
Each user on the site has a list of stock tickers and the goal is to present him with articles that correspond to the list of shares each user has.

For example, the search engine will search for articles and display only if there are 2 tickers of shares or more within the article (and if the article has only one ticker then it will also display it)

I'd love to know if anyone knows how to do it. Thanks in advance

the stock list of user number 1 is **'aapl:us,spy:us,intc:us,goog:us'** Then only articles that have more than 2 shares ticker inside will be shown to him (and if there is only one stock mentioned in the article then it will also be displayed to him too)

```
 <?php
    $list = 'aapl:us,spy:us,intc:us,goog:us';
    $ticker = explode(",",$list);
    $count = count($ticker);
    $pha="";
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $pha.= " = ".$ticker[$i]." OR ";
    }  

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ticker ".$pha;
$result = $db->prepare($query); 
$result->execute(); 

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo '<li><a href="category.html?i='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></li>';
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `REGEXP` function, which can solve your problem

**For searching**

From

```
$list = 'aapl:us,spy:us,intc:us,goog:us';
```

To

```
$list = '(^|,)aapl:us|spy:us|intc:us|goog:us(,|$)';

# OR without modifying your list just replace comma with pipe
$list = 'aapl:us,spy:us,intc:us,goog:us';
$list = '(^|,)'.str_replace(',', '|', $list).'(,|$)';
```

And

From

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ticker ".$pha;
```

To

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ticker REGEXP $list";
```

Which is will be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ticker REGEXP (^|,)aapl:us|spy:us|intc:us|goog:us(,|$)
```

**For having specific number of ticker create query string like below**

```
SELECT *,((ticker REGEXP '(^|,)aapl:us(,|$)') + (ticker REGEXP '(^|,)spy:us(,|$)') ) as sum 
FROM 
        table 
HAVING sum = 2
```

**Test sum to understand what we are doing**

```
mysql> -- test variable
mysql> set @test='aapl:us,spy:us,intc:us,goog:us';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- variable contents
mysql> select @test;
+--------------------------------+
| @test                          |
+--------------------------------+
| aapl:us,spy:us,intc:us,goog:us |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- if you create sum it can be used in having clause
mysql> select ((@test REGEXP '(^|,)aapl:us(,|$)') + (@test REGEXP '(^|,)spy:us(,|$)') ) as sum;
+------+
| sum  |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- for 2 ticker
mysql> select * from( select ((@test REGEXP '(^|,)aapl:us(,|$)') + (@test REGEXP '(^|,)spy:us(,|$)') ) as sum ) as q having sum =2;
+------+
| sum  |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- for 3 or more ticker
mysql> select * from( select ((@test REGEXP '(^|,)aapl:us(,|$)') + (@test REGEXP '(^|,)spy:us(,|$)') ) as sum ) as q having sum >=3;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**Script to produce query**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php

 $list = 'aapl:us,spy:us,intc:us,goog:us';

 $sum  = '('.implode("+", array_map(function($v){ return sprintf("(ticker REGEXP '(^|,)%s(,|$)')",$v); },explode(",",$list))).')';

 $query = "SELECT *, $sum as sum from table having sum = 2";

 print $query.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
SELECT *, ((ticker REGEXP '(^|,)aapl:us(,|$)')+(ticker REGEXP '(^|,)spy:us(,|$)')+(ticker REGEXP '(^|,)intc:us(,|$)')+(ticker REGEXP '(^|,)goog:us(,|$)')) as sum from table having sum = 2
```

Comment: the search engine will search for articles and display only if there are 2 tickers of shares or more within the article (and if the article has only one ticker then it will also display it) ? @akshay TIA

Comment: @AnnaLA see I edited my answer this can solve I guess

Comment: hi... its not working "Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '^|,)aapl:us|spy:us|intc:us|goog:us(,|$)' at line 1 )"

Comment: @AnnaLA, see second part in which each word will be summed

Comment: @AnnaLA added php script also which will produce query string

Comment: look good thank you a lot... id i want to add to the query WHERE and SORT can i do it? for example i would like to ORDER "sum" number (if the article have 3 tickers will shown before an article with 2 tickers) TIA

Comment: @AnnaLA order by will be in the end, hope you can solve now.